# How to pass redux store in Provider when using ReactDom.render() to the rendering element?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a React class, which is rendered inside the `react-redux`'s `Provider`.

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <First/>
</Provider>
```

Hence I can easily use `react-redux`'s `mapDispatchToProps` and `mapStateToProps` inside the `First`.

But in `First`, I am rendering another component like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
      React.createElement(Second),
      document.getElementById('preview-right')
    );
```

But inside `Second` component, I cannot access the initial store provided by the `Provider`. I know I can pass the store here as a prop taking the store from context of the `First`component, but I don't want to use that, as I want to maintain consistency and call the `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` directly inside the `Second`.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you are trgeting a different container for a child component?  You can call react-dom's render to render the top-most root component of your SPA, it's child components will still render.  You can sort out the composition and styling with child elements of this root component.

Use **[`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)** to, erm... *connect* a component with a store bound to one of its parents

You be able to use `maptStateToProps` *and* `mapDispatchToProps` in any child component of first by using the [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) method of React-Redux.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Second)
```

You can then remove the call to react-dom's render method in any child component and just have the one